# report builder max with expr

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, reportbuilder3.0

I have a report with MS report builder 3.0 that includes an expr failed to count no of passes(yes/no per user). Now I give that field a label name call NPasses, and I was trying to get the max with expr but did not work I got an error.

How do I go about this. taking into account that this max is a count from other faild. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using group by the field I wanted to max and then count it with another fieled with iff yes or if no. the data type I had was bit. so this what worked for me =SUM(IIF(Fields!Pass.Value=0 ,0,1))